# Current Menu to Highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this navigation bar and a local storage script which pages through a list by clicking next or previous. When you first enter the page, Overview is the first page to be shown and it is highlighted bydefault (class=first).

Till you are in the overview page and click Next Previous everything works but when you are in another navigation menu eg Qualifications and then click Next/Previous then the page redirects to the Overview page. It should remain in the Qualification page and the qualification menu should be highlighted.

An idea was suggested ? Clicking Next >> Find the xth element of the nav >> get the url, redirect to URL. Your help would be appreciated.(FYI-- Clicking next previous changes the Url)

Image attached to help you.

http://oi48.tinypic.com/2lo6mhe.jpg

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="on-click-tab.html">OVERVIEW</a></li>
        <li><a href="on-click-tab1.html">PERSONAL DETAILS</a></li>
        <li><a href="on-click-tab2.html">QUALIFICATION</a></li>
        <li><a href="on-click-tab3.html">REFERENCES</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    // this will get the full URL at the address bar
    var url = window.location.href; 

    // passes on every "a" tag 
    $("#nav a").each(function() {
        // checks if its the same on the address bar
        if(url == (this.href)) {
            $('ul li.first').removeClass('first');
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("current");
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="next">
    <input type="image" src="/images/button-right.gif" name="Next" id="Next" value="Next »" onclick="javascript:GetNext();">
</div>
```

-

```
function GetNext(){  
$("#no-more").html(" ");
var Pointer = localStorage.getItem('0');
Pointer++;
if (localStorage.getItem(Pointer) === null) {
    $("#no-more").html("There are no further applicants from your list").addClass('message-nm');
} else {
    var NextURL = localStorage.getItem(Pointer);
        localStorage.setItem('0', Pointer); 
    var totalItems = localStorage.length -1 ;
    var GoURL= NextURL.substring(NextURL.indexOf('~')+1);
    window.location.replace( GoURL ) ;
    $("#no-more").html('Working...').addClass('message-nm');
}
}

var totalItems = localStorage.length -1 ;
$("#progress").html(localStorage.getItem("0") + " of " + totalItems);
```

Comment: Can you provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: Sorry, Dom I am afraid I cannot as the site uses a https and is not accessible to the outside network or I would love to show it to you. However, I have put a simplified question of this here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152590/highlight-current-page-after-page-loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152590/highlight-current-page-after-page-loads)