# Highlight Current Page after Page Loads

Tags: jquery, navigation

Help needed...I have this navigation bar

```
    <div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li id="overview" class="first"><a href="start?nhsyshhdyye%sdfsd">OVERVIEW</a></li>
    <li id="details" class=”current”><a href="start?ertrer%sdsde%srerte "> DETAILS</a></li>
    <li id="questions" ><a href="start?opuuwe%sjiwue ">QUESTIONS</a></li>
    <li id="review" ><a href="start?sdfw%wrfwlwer ">REVIEWS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div><!---Details Page Start--->

<div><!---other content---></div>
<div> <input type="submit" name="answer-save" id=" answer-save" value="Save" class="save-btn" style="width:100px;">
 </div>
<div><!---other content---></div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="answer-save1" id=" answer-save1" value="Save" class="save-btn" style="width:100px;"> 
</div>
<div><!---other content---></div>
</div>
```

There are quite a few submit buttons which saves the edited input of the page. Eg, change of name or adds a comment etc. When the page loads after saving/editing, the url changes. [ start?ertrer%sdsde%srerte becomes start?someother%^url but the page remains the same] How do I keep the class as current when the page loads ?

I had used this script but as the url changes when the page loads script is pointless now.

```
var url = window.location.href; 
// passes on every "a" tag 
$("#nav a").each(function() {
        // checks if its the same on the address bar
    if(url == (this.href)) { 
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("current");
    }
});
```

Help ????

Comment: Try using `post` in form submit

Comment: Hi! Mohammad, I cannot use post or have access to <body> tag..;o(( It has to be with Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your markup like so to include the query string value:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="overview" class="first" data-qs="nhsyshhdyye%sdfsd"><a href="start?nhsyshhdyye%sdfsd">OVERVIEW</a></li>
    <li id="details" data-qs="ertrer%sdsde%srerte"><a href="start?ertrer%sdsde%srerte "> DETAILS</a></li>
    <!--etc.-->
</ul>
```

Then add a line of script, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul#menu li[data-qs=" + location.search.replace("?", "") + "]").addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I found a simplier way by adding div / class to the container of the page and  a script finds the div/class and if found puts class(curent) to the li with particular id.

<ul id="nav">
    <li id="overview" >OVERVIEW</a></li>
<li id="details" >DETAILS</a></li>
<li id="questions" >QUESTIONS</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tc-overview"><!---OVERVIEW CONTENT---></div>
if ($(".tc-overview").length > 0){
    $("#nav #overview").addClass("current");}

Works but if anyone has a better solution, it would be greatly appreciated. Shame I have to put the script on all of the pages.